# How to use autocomplete in a datagrid?

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, autocomplete

I have a Datagrid with a DataGridTextColumn. This is populated by using databinding, and can be edited by users.

Is it possible to add autocomplete to the DataGridTextColumn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. However, if you use a DataGridTemplateColumn - you could use the AutoCompleteBox from the [WPF Toolki](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)t in the Template for the Column.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.I have tried it many times.You can use AutoCompleteBox from the datagrid or from the autocomplete predefined libraries.